# How to fix a cloned AMI with another domain SSL certificate on it for Wordpress on AWS?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, bitnami, amazon-ami

In 2018 I made a Wordpress site by using a Bitnami AMI for a AWS EC2. Fine developed a site and created another custom AMI of the finalized Wordpress site. This was for domain X.

Now in 2020 I wanted to duplicate that website by using this custom AMI for domain Y. I have created an EC2 based on that custom AMI and instance went online without problems.

The problem is now that I can not reach the site by its url, I got blocked by "This connection is invalid", I also see that certificate is still based on the domain of 2018, thus is invalid. So I think that the issue is caused by the SSL configuration based on domain X while it is iinitiated for domain Y. But since I am not able to reach the site neither the admin panel, I am wondering how I can disable the SSL/HTTPS enforcement so that I can reach the site and admin panel?

I do have access to SSH, so probably I should be able to do something from there? But totally not known with that type OS and usage via SSH.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

As you created a snapshot of the 2018 instance, the new instance has the same configuration you had at that time. Please check the following items so you can update the certificates and the app's configuration to work properly using your new domain name:

- The certificates are configured in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf folder by default. You probably substituted the ones we include with valid certificate files for your domain in 2018. You will need to substitute the server.crt and server.key now with the new ones.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/enable-https-ssl-apache/

- Regarding the WordPress configuration, we have configuration tool that takes care of updating the domain name in the database. Can you take a look at this guide?

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/configuration/configure-custom-domain/

You will basically need to run `sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/bnconfig --machine_hostname my-new-domain.com`.

I also suggest you check the WordPress' configuration file (/opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-config.php) to see if you edited the WP_HOME and WP_SITE parameters there.